# Select option same width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/73vbu0kg/

```
select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 39px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 218px;
}
select option {
  padding: 7px 15px;
}
```

Why option field is wider than select? How do you fit it to same width both select and option with same text padding?

Comment: Because you are adding padding to the option. Refer http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you have hidden overflow on the text id because in your `CSS` you are giving the `select` a fixed `width`. If you remove the width it will expand to the width it needs to display all of the `option` values. If you don't want the select bigger then that leaves you with changing the `font-size`

```css
select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 39px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
select option {
  padding: 7px 15px;
}
```

```html
<select>
<option selected="selected" value="">Please select one:</option>
<option value="1">Prayer Requests</option>
<option value="2">Financial Assistance</option>
<option value="3">Life, Illness & Loss</option>
<option value="4">Marriage, Relationship & Family</option>
<option value="5">Life Controlling Issues & Addictions</option>
<option value="6">Counseling & Life Improvement</option>
<option value="7">Other</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your style as below

```
select option {
  padding: 7px 4px;
}
```